# Python cairo save figure as np array gives weird results

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, cairo

Try to run my example:

```
import numpy as np
import cairo
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

img_size = 28
size = 0.8
color = (255, 0, 0)
thickness = 2

data = np.zeros((img_size, img_size, 3), dtype=np.uint8)
surface = cairo.ImageSurface.create_for_data(
  data, cairo.FORMAT_RGB16_565, img_size, img_size
)
cr = cairo.Context(surface)

# fill with solid white
cr.set_source_rgb(1, 1, 1)
cr.paint()


size = img_size * size - thickness
cr.rectangle((img_size - size) / 2, (img_size - size) / 2, size, size)
cr.set_line_width(thickness)
cr.set_source_rgb(*color)
cr.stroke()

surface.write_to_png("shape.png")
plt.imshow(data)
plt.savefig("shape_from_np.png")
```

shape.png looks like:

[image]

shape_from_np.png looks like:

[image]

I was thinking maybe I missed the format, or channels/shape, but if I print out the red layer like `data[:,:,0]`, it shows weird 0 values at the bottom half as well, and I'm not sure why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In documentation I found `ImageSurface.create_from_png(...)` so I used your `'shape.png'` to test what values it will use for PNG image.

```
import cairo

surface = cairo.ImageSurface.create_from_png('shape.png')

print('format:', surface.get_format())
print('width :', surface.get_width())
print('height:', surface.get_height())
print('stride:', surface.get_stride())
print('stride/width:', surface.get_stride()/surface.get_width())
```

and this gives

```
format: 1
width : 28
height: 28
stride: 112
stride/width: 4.0
```

I found that `format: 1` means `cairo.Format.RGB24` and in doc [cairo.Format](https://pycairo.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/enums.html#cairo.Format) I found it needs `32bit` pixel which means `4` bytes in

```
data = np.zeros((img_size, img_size, 4), dtype=np.uint8)
```

and the same `4` gives me `stride/width` (`stride/28`)

---

Using these values I can create correct image but `BGR` instead of `RGB`

[image]

So it still needs some changes.

---

But `cv2` uses `BGR` images and it saves it correctly without changes.

```
import cv2
cv2.imwrite('cv2.png', data)
```

---

```
import numpy as np
import cairo
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

img_size = 28
size = 0.8
color = (255, 0, 0)
thickness = 2

data = np.zeros((img_size, img_size, 4), dtype=np.uint8)

surface = cairo.ImageSurface.create_for_data(data, cairo.FORMAT_RGB24, img_size, img_size)
cr = cairo.Context(surface)

# fill with solid white
cr.set_source_rgb(1, 1, 1)
cr.paint()

size = int(img_size * size) - thickness
cr.rectangle((img_size - size) / 2, (img_size - size) / 2, size, size)
cr.set_line_width(thickness)
cr.set_source_rgb(*color)
cr.stroke()

plt.imshow(data)
plt.savefig("shape_from_np.png")

surface.write_to_png("shape.png")

import cv2
cv2.imwrite('cv2.png', data)
```

---

Doc: [ImageSurface](https://pycairo.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/surfaces.html?highlight=ImageSurface#cairo.ImageSurface), [Format](https://pycairo.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/enums.html#cairo.Format)

Comment: I see, with RGB16_565, the last axis has a size of 2. RGB24 has a size of 4. I would expect the last axis to have size of 3, one for red, green, and blue respectively. In this case they don't mean that?

Comment: I had a closer look, and the last (4th) element on last axis seems to be just a placeholder. So if we remove that, and flip the values, it will work: `np.flip(data[:,:,:3], -1)`.

Comment: even in documentation for [RGB24](https://pycairo.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/enums.html#cairo.Format.RGB24) you can read `"pixel is a 32-bit quantity, with the upper 8 bits unused."` I think it can use one method for `RGB24` and `ARGB32` which use this place for alpha channel.